# how to try-catch c assert?

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm using a third framework, which is a C code framework. My app will crash because there are many `assert()` calls in that framework. Is there a way to disable those assert or try-catch them in Objective-C ?

Comment: Why are the assertions failing?  Have you tried to not violate their constraints?

Comment: You can define NDEBUG in Build Settings->Preprocessor Macros to disable assert.

Comment: @NickVeys I don't know why, but my app will crash by SIGABRT.